# angular bootstrap ngb rating value divide in markup

Tags: angular, angular8, ng-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I have this ngb rating control:

```
<ngb-rating [(rate)]="x.popularity" (hover)="hovered=$event" (leave)="hovered=0" [readonly]="true"></ngb-rating>
```

I want to split the x.popularity / 10 for the rate value in order to accommodate to the default 10 stars in ngb rating but I'm not able to do that. I can't modify the model so I'm looking for options how I can divide the value by 10 in order to set the correct value in the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Banana in a box syntax `[()]` is syntactic sugar. So `[(rate)]="x.popularity"` is short for `[rate]="x.popularity" (rateChange)="x.popularity=$event"`.

So in your case something like this should work:

```
<ngb-rating [rate]="x.popularity*10" (rateChange)="x.popularity=$event/10" (hover)="hovered=$event" (leave)="hovered=0" [readonly]="true">
```